# a good tool to analyse iptables log?

Tags: security, iptables, logging

I have some linux server with iptables and I'm looking for an offline tool that allow log analysis to detect suspicious activity .

I dont think that installing a web tool is a good choice beacause it's another possible hole in the system so I'm looking for an offline one that generate human-readable summary.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), but might be salvageable.  The bigger problem is you haven't really defined your requirements well enough for us to give you an answer --  Immediate questions that spring to mind: Are you looking for a command-line tool (what it sounds like)? What *kind* of "suspicious activity" do you want to look for? What kinds of logs do you want to crunch? -- If you can clarify your question I'll reopen it and see if we can get you some answers...